# Calculating working hours time difference in PHP

Tags: php

I wanted to calculate the number of hours between the encoded date and completion date. As of now I can compute the time difference between the two datetimes excluding the Saturdays and Sundays. My problem is I need to exclude the lunch breaks (12:00 am to 1:00 pm) and holidays.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
function business_hours($start, $end){

    $startDate = new DateTime($start);
    $endDate = new DateTime($end);
    $periodInterval = new DateInterval( "PT1H" );

    $period = new DatePeriod( $startDate, $periodInterval, $endDate );
    $count = 0;

    $holidays = [
      "Human Rights Day"      => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-03-21'),
      "Good Friday"           => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-03-30'),
      "Family Day"            => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-04-02'),
      "Freedom Day"           => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-04-27'),
      "Labour Day"            => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-05-01'),
      "Youth Day"             => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-06-16'),
      "National Women's Day"  => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-08-09'),
      "Heritage Day"          => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-09-24'),
      "Day of Reconciliation" => new DateTime(date('Y') . '-12-16'),
    ];

    foreach($period as $date){

    $startofday = clone $date;
    $startofday->setTime(8,00);

    $endofday = clone $date;
    $endofday->setTime(17,00);

        if($date > $startofday && $date <= $endofday && !in_array($date->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday'))){
            $count++;
        }

    }
    echo $count;
}

$start = '2020-02-14 08:00:00';
$end = '2020-02-17 08:00:00';

$go = business_hours($start,$end);

//output 9 hours
?>
```

As per my code, I set the working hours from 8:00 to 17:00 and then excluded the Saturdays and Sundays. As per my example the output will be 9 (*including the lunch break*). How can I exclude the lunch break and holidays?

**Update**

The completion time can be more than 1 day. For example, the start date/time is 2020-02-14 08:00:00 and the completion time is 2020-02-19 08:00:00 the output is 27 hours. The calculation should exclude the lunch breaks of each day that have 12:00am to 1:00pm and holidays in between.

**Update**
I added an array of holidays, how can I exclude these holidays?

Comment: Do you have the lunch break defined or is it a static number?

Comment: @Mech yes it is defined it is one hour from 12:00 am to 13:00 pm/1:00pm

Comment: are you looking to display that the lunch break is at that set time? ie 08:00-12:00, 13:00-17:00?

Comment: otherwise, just -1 hour from it

Comment: @Mech I wanted to exclude the lunch break and holidays from the calculation of the total hours difference

Comment: @Mech I considered add -1 to the calculation but what if the starttime is 8:00am and the completed time is 9:00am of the same day the output will be 0

Comment: Assuming labour laws say you get a lunch after a 6.5 hour shift, you could do if ($count > 6.5) { echo ($count - 1); } else { echo $count; }

Comment: @Mech how about if the $count is equals to 18 hours?

Comment: That's a shift I wouldn't want! lol. Would that mean 2 lunches or is it more variable than that?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Comment: @Mech no it is not a shift, my system calculates the investigation time. I required the total number of hours that the investigators took to finish their investigation. Sometimes it takes 2 to 3 days to finish.

Comment: just add in the loop inside the if condition and check whether its not equal to 12th hour, for the holidays, you'll need to have a defined holidays

Comment: @Kevin oh ok I got it, how about the holiday? I wanted to exclude the holidays.

Comment: If you are doing this to create a time clock for employees, you need to store the data into a database... probably MySQL. Your code should reflect real world usage.

Comment: @StackSlave the calculation is for their SLA or efficiency rating no need for to save this in the database just the computation is needed

Comment: @lawrenceagulto you need to define your holidays and do that on your own, i don't know which holidays you follow in your country. some holidays are constant, (labor day and such), and there are holidays that are dynamic (holy week, chinese new year, ramadan)

Comment: you can just hardcode everything first, or get an api if you want

Answer (score -1, accepted):

how about try add some condition inside loop each day to skip some hours

```
($date->format('H') <= 12 || $date->format('H') > 13)
```

it will skip if hour above 12 to 13 (if you use 24 format hour)

```
if($date > $startofday && $date <= $endofday && !in_array($date->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday')) && ($date->format('H') <= 12 || $date->format('H') > 13)){

   $count++;

}
```

**UPDATE**

okay if your "holydays" is cutom maybe be good to add some paramerter to your function to store list of your holydays

```
function business_hours($start, $end,$holyDays = null){
  //another line
}
```

and check every loop of dates is in on holydays list or not

```
in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $holyDays)
```

you will get filter of break time and custom holyday

```
function business_hours($start, $end,$holyDays = null){

    $startDate = new DateTime($start);
    $endDate = new DateTime($end);
    $periodInterval = new DateInterval( "PT1H" );

    $period = new DatePeriod( $startDate, $periodInterval, $endDate );
    $count = 0;



    foreach($period as $date){
        $startofday = clone $date;
        $startofday->setTime(8,00);
        $endofday = clone $date;
        $endofday->setTime(17,00);

        //just some var to use in conditional check
        $notHolyday = true;

        //now check the array of holyday and check if in range dates is same with holydays we have
        if($holyDays != null && is_array($holyDays) && in_array($date->format('Y-m-d'), $holyDays)){
            $notHolyday = false;
        }

        if($date > $startofday && $date <= $endofday && !in_array($date->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday')) && ($date->format('H') <= 12 || $date->format('H') > 13) && $notHolyday){
            $count++;

        }

    }
    echo $count;
}

$start = '2020-02-14 08:00:00';
$end = '2020-02-19 08:00:00';
$holyDays = array('2020-02-17','2020-02-18');
$count = business_hours($start,$end,$holyDays);

echo $count;
```

i hope this is want you want

Comment: The code is ok the only problem now is the holidays

Comment: well if your "holydays" not just weekend you can add one parameter to yout function to define your holydays

Comment: i just update my answer i hope this what you looking for

Comment: Thank you this is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a static/defined lunch break, you can use the following logic:

- If $startDate is a weekday, and before 12:00, that's the start date for lunch calculation; otherwise it's the next weekday.
- If the $endDate is a weekday, and after 13:00, that's the end date for lunch calculation; otherwise, it's the previous weekday
- Actual number of lunch breaks equals the difference between those recalculated dates, at one hour each.
  The following is pseudocode:

```
    if(!in_array($startDate->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday')) && ($startDate->format('g') < 12) {
        $startForLunch = $startDate;
    }
    else {
        $startForLunch = new DateTime($start, '+1 day');
        while(in_array($startDate->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday'))){
            $startForLunch->add('1 day');
        }
    }

    if(!in_array($endDate->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday')) && ($endDate->format('g') > 13) {
        $endForLunch = $end;
    }
    else {
        $endForLunch = new DateTime($endDate, '-1 day');
        while(in_array($endDate->format('l'), array('Sunday','Saturday'))){
            $endForLunch->add('-1 day');
        }
    }
    $lunchPeriods = $endForLunch - $startForLunch + 1;
```

Comment: I am getting an error on endForLunch = new DateTime($endDate, '-1 day'); the error is **Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given**

Comment: I should have used the parameters sent into the function. It is "pseudocode," not real. I just tried to write something readable enough for you to follow the logic and develop a proper solution.